# Trying to get nginx status from a remote machine

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get stats from nginx from a remote machine.  I added the ip address of the remote machine in the nginx config but when I run curl on the remote machine I get forbidden.  How to I resovle?  I reloaded the config.

```
       location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;   
            access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
            deny all;
        }


curl http://mysite/nginx_status
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.13</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you get the solution? I am having the same problem. and this `ec2metadata --local-ipv4` is unavailable on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon resolves IP's different internally. You should use the internal IP rather than the public-ipv4 address.

Log in to your server and run this:

`ec2metadata --local-ipv4`

```
ubuntu@ip-10-244-231-180:~$ ec2metadata --local-ipv4
10.244.231.180
```

Providing that your instances are within the same region, you should use this IP address instead.

```
   location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;   
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 10.244.231.180;
        deny all;
    }
```

You could also use

`allow 10.0.0.0/8;` (although it's untested)

Comment: Just for debugging, I added `allow all;` to Nginx configuration and it worked. so it seems that the request is coming from an IP other than 127.0.0.1 and I should find the docker internal IP address for the network Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue, i could not able to get nginx server status in remote machine.

Instead i was getting 403 forbidden error in web browser.

I made some modification in "nginx.conf" file which was in this path "/usr/local/nginx_fstack/conf".  so things worked well for me.

Previously nginx.conf file was like this

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;

            access_log off;
            allow xx.xx.xx.xx/24;
            deny all;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I edited like this

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;

            access_log off;
            allow xx.xx.xx.xx/24;
            deny all;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

So later from the browser "xx.xx.xx.xx/nginx_status" i got proper status like this below:

```
Active connections: 54 
server accepts handled requests
12594 12594 12543 
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 53
```

Things worked well for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the remote machine really has the IP you wrote into the config? What IP address is it? You can be behind NAT or sthg...

Also check the error log of Nginx, you should have some useful info available there... (I hope I rememeber correctly that it's written there. Anyway, why is access log off? At least for debugging you could use it...)

Comment: 2012/03/25 08:15:45 [error] 649#0: *2000 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxxxxxx-1.compute.amazonaws.com"

Comment: The above is what I got when I turned access on